# Создание HashMap с ключом по первой букве

Tags: java

Получаем список слов из файла, и содается мапа, где ключ - первая буква слова, а значения - список слов, которые на нее начинаются

Примерный код ниже  но так, понятное дело, в значения записываются все слова из листа.
Не могу сообразить, как сделать запись значений только удовлетворяющих условию

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Map<String, List> findMap = new HashMap<>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(/*file*/));
    String str;
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
        if (!str.isEmpty()) {
            list.add(str); 
        }
    }

    for (String s : list) {
        if (s.startsWith(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)))) {
            result.add(s);
            findMap.put(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)),result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно примерно так:

```
public Map<String, List<String>> createMap(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), Charset.defaultCharset()).stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(word -> word.substring(0, 1), Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Такой вид коллекции Map называется Multimap, т.е. ключ соответствует множеству значений. К сожалению, среди стандартных коллекций в джаве нет имплементации Multimap, поэтому приходится создавать Map , содержащий в себе List. В данном случае задача достаточно тривиальная, поэтому подобное решение имеет право на существование. В целом при необходимости использования Multimap можно найти готовую реализацию в альтернативных коллекциях. Например, коллекции Guava. С ними работать на много проще и кода нужно меньше. Кстати, альтенативные коллекции предоставляют множество интересных реализаций. Например BiMap, т.е. коллекция типа ключ-ключ, либо коллекции, работающие с примитивами и т.д.

Comment: @ IR42 Collectors.mapping принимает 2 аргумента: Function, Collector. Собственно, это Function. разумеется, это не единственный способ получить Multimap

Comment: @ IR42 согласен, можно и так, поскольку groupingBy работает не только с Supplier, но и с Collector. результат один и тот же, но немного лаконичне